# How do I synchronize my function calls in node js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Here's my routes.js

```
app.route('/api/book/:id')
        .get(function(req,res){
            var id=req.params.id;
            bookapi.getBookDetails(id,res);
        });
```

and here's the function it calls

```
scope.getBookDetails=function(bookId,res){
    console.log('unnecessary thing@@');
    //var bookId=req.params.id;
    connection.query({
        sql:"SELECT name,description FROM books WHERE books.id=?",
        values:[bookId]
    },
    function (err,results) {
        if(err) throw err;

        if(results.length>0){
            var x=scope.getGenre(bookId);
            console.log(x +"hello");
            res.send(JSON.stringify(results)+scope.getAuthors(bookId)+scope.getGenre(bookId));
        }
    }
    )
}
```

I'm using angular too so when a get request is sent to '/books/:bookId' it calls this controller:

function($scope,$routeParams,$http){

```
$http.get('/api/book/'+$routeParams.bookId).success(function(bookdetails){
            $scope.bookdetails=bookdetails;
        })
    }
```

This is my server-side console:

```
unnecessary thing@@
undefinedhello
GET /api/book/1 304 16.577 ms - -
```

In my client-side console i get the response

```
[{"name":"The Alchemist","description":""}]undefinedundefined
```

In my server side console getBookDetails is being called before id=1 could even be passed through '/api/book/1'. Why is this happening? Why isn't it synchronous? Should I learn async for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assigning `req.params.id` to a variable `id` is always synchronous, so the problem is not there. The problem may be that `getGenre` and `getAuthors` are asynchronous so have to move anything dependant on their result to a callback function.

One easier way to do so is by using promises. A very fun to learn JavaScript promise library is `bluebird`. It should make things a lot easier for you.

```
app.route('/api/book/:id')
    .get(function(req,res){
        var id=req.params.id;
        bookapi.getBookDetails(id).then(function(result){
            res.send(result)
        });
    });

scope.getBookDetails=function(bookId){
    console.log('unnecessary thing@@');
    //var bookId=req.params.id;
    return Promise.promisify(connection.query)({
        sql:"SELECT name,description FROM books WHERE books.id=?",
        values:[bookId]
    })
    .then(function (results) {
        if(results.length>0){
            return Promise.props({
                // getGernre should return a promise just like this function.
                // if it accepts a callback, you can do
                // Promise.promisify(scope.getGenre) and use that instead
                genre: scope.getGenre(bookId),
                authors: scope.getAuthors(bookId),
                results: results,
            })
        }
    })
    .then(function (dict){
        if(dict){
            console.log(dict.genre +"hello");
            return JSON.stringify(dict.results)+dict.authors+dict.genre;
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: thank you for your time. promise seems to be a viable solution. however, i still don't understand why the getBookDetails function is called before the GET /api/book/1 request is even sent .

Comment: it doesn't, you can write `console.log(bookId)`  at the beginning  of getBookDetails and it should print 1

Comment: This is driving me crazy, time to go back and learn things from the start.Using callbacks will lead to making too many functions. Using promises will mean I have to learn something new again.